# PHP writing to file without truncation

Tags: php

I am creating a flatfile database, and I am trying to solve the problem of multiple edits being made at the same time. I understand I need to truncate the file for editing and deleting rows but for adding rows this is not necessary.

So if I were to use `fopen($file, 'a')` to write to a file, and multiple people where to open the file and write to it, would they all be able to write to the file simultaneously?

Without truncating the file people shouldn't be overwriting each other right?

Comment: @Bracketworks I didn't opt out of it myself, I would use if I could.

Comment: Understandably, however SQLite has a really small footprint and (*AFAIK*) can transparently stand in for a flat-file architecture, requiring only the PHP extension and the filesystem permissions needed for a flat-file architecture anyways. Again though, understandably; I've worked myself with rigorous and seemingly ludicrous requirements.

Comment: @Bracketworks aye SQLite was my first thought, but as you seem too know all to well about, it's not my choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use some kind of helper for this.

PHP function [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) (File LOCK)

```
//Open the File Stream
$handle = fopen($file,"a");

//Lock File, error if unable to lock
if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
    $data;
    // do anything to fill variable $data
    fwrite($handle, $data);    //Write the $data into file
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN);    //Unlock File
} else {
    echo "Could not Lock File!";
}

//Close Stream
fclose($handle);
```

[PHP file write threading issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663229/php-file-write-threading-issues)
[Read and write to a file while keeping lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450850/read-and-write-to-a-file-while-keeping-lock)

Comment: @George this will solve the issue, as the users can overwrite each other and this code will automaticaly wait for lock release. Or is there any other issue?

Comment: I would use this for editing and deleting parts of the file but I want people to be able to open it concurrently instead of being locked out. Just wondering if i don't truncate the file would contents get overwritten or is data just appended to the file.

Comment: @George if you open file in "a" mode, there is still possibility to overwrite each other. You still have to lock. Write operation is not taking more than 2/10 second and it's worth to do it securely