# Setting a time limit for flock()

Tags: php, flock

Sometimes my server freezes after a call `flock()`, and only rebooting it will unfreeze it.

This happens because PHP's `flock()` ignores the execution time limit and some errors when `LOCK_UN` is used.

**Question:** How can I set the time limit for `flock()`?

This must work without `LOCK_NB`, because if I use that I get errors with parallel scripts (The queue sequence gets broken).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php flock behaviour when file is locked by one process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833448/php-flock-behaviour-when-file-is-locked-by-one-process)

Comment: I've cleaned up some of the English and formatting, but since I don't know much PHP, I might have left some stuff out.