# What happens if file_put_contents can't lock?

Tags: php, file

Assume multiple people write to the same file at the same time with the command

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'This is an example', LOCK_EX);
```

would it be possible that one person might not be able to write to the file, because the function `file_put_contents` had to wait too long for the locked file? Would the function throw an exception, or would you just end up with a error like this:

> "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of .. seconds exceeded"

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833448/php-flock-behaviour-when-file-is-locked-by-one-process help?

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like execution timeout for the script (time taking to execute the script is beyond the configured value as process is waiting to accurire the ) , there will be default timeout you can check the default max-execution-time in php.ini file

```
max-execution-time=30
```

you can tune the timeout and check
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php or max-execution-time