# How to generate an ID for Contact Form?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHP for a simple Contact Form. I'm trying to generate an unique ID for each form submitted. For example, the first email is #001, the second #002, 3th #003 etc.

I'll use the ID in the autoreply (or autoresponse?) e-mail: *"You are the #016 person to make contact."*, for example.

Can be with PHP or JavaScript (can it be with JS? I don't know! But I prefer PHP!). But I have no idea about how I can do this.

***I'm not using a database.***

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read and write to a file while keeping lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450850/read-and-write-to-a-file-while-keeping-lock)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're (probably) going to store received information in a kind of database, you generate id on insertion into database. Autoincrement ID field should do the trick.

edit: It also sounds reasonable to reuse [google forms](https://sites.google.com/site/siteshelphowtos/google-sites-instructions/Gadgets/addacontactform)

Comment: I'm not using a database :/

Comment: what do you do with form data then?

Comment: it's a simple contact form: On my website, the user sends a message (with an ID) and I get in my email.

Comment: if you really need to have an increasing unique number as email id, you will have to store it somehow anyway. It should be failproof to race condition, so it should support some kind of a transaction or involve setlock magick. So, the simplest way is to use database, or use google forms

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. The most simple of those is to create a file which will store the number of form filled and you can increase its value for each form filled.

Here is the example copied from: [Read and write to a file while keeping lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450850/read-and-write-to-a-file-while-keeping-lock)

```
//Open the File Stream
$handle = fopen("file.txt","r+");

//Lock File, error if unable to lock
if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
    $count = fread($handle, filesize("file.txt"));    //Get Current Hit Count
    $count = $count + 1;    //Increment Hit Count by 1
    ftruncate($handle, 0);    //Truncate the file to 0
    fwrite($handle, $count);    //Write the new Hit Count
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN);    //Unlock File
} else {
    echo "Could not Lock File!";
}

//Close Stream
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: it's subject to race conditions

Comment: @Marat I don't think he will ever encounter a race condition

Comment: well, it's a website. One day it'll hit two requests about the same time

Comment: @Marat That can be solved by opening the file using an exclusive lock. That way processes have to wait their turn, eliminating race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's uniqid() function to generate unique id each time.

Update 1:
    It's a very useful function. The probability of generating same id is really minimum. For more information please visit [the link](http://php.net/uniqid)

Update 2:
    You can use simple text file/csv to store one line at a time to keep track of it. When the user submit the form you generate unique id each time and reply to client and at the same time you store it to a normal text file if you like. Hope this will help.

Comment: I must have a database?