# How to create an entry ID

Tags: php

It's just how it sounds...

I have an HTML5 form, and no database. (I did not suggest/support this. I'm simply adapting to the environment.)

In order to save entries on the server, I've decided to write them to a sibling .CSV file.

I need an easy way of referencing these entries for logic later down the road, which is where the Entry ID necessity comes in.

I've googled around and couldn't find any methods--both procedural and programmatic--that might be of use. Though that may be due to my inexperience.

To summarize: How would I create a locally unique Entry ID string/int in a PHP file that runs every time a form is submitted?

Comment: Why not have another file with the actual ID?

Comment: How so? @KIMB-technologies

Comment: I'm not even really sure what you're asking.  Are you just looking for this?: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another text file where you can store the actual ID.

e.g:

```
<?php
  //Get last ID
  $lastid = file_get_contents( 'last_id.txt' );
  if( empty( $lastid ) ){ $lastid = 0 );
  $thisid = $lastid + 1;

  //save post data to CSV
  //use $lastid 

  //save for next time
  file_put_contents( 'last_id.txt', $thisid );

?>
```

If I have got your point right.

**EDIT:**

You have a POST Request and save the data to a CSV file. There you need an unique ID to mark the row.

e.g: your files would look like:

csv_data.txt

```
1, Max, Mustermann
2, Otto, Muster
```

last_id.txt

```
 2
```

If a new request comes to the server you will get the last added ID from out last_id.txt and increase this value. This increased value will be your next unique ID. 
Now you would add the next row to your CSV file:

```
3, Ben, Miller
```

And at the end you would save the unique ID (in this case 3) to your last_id.txt. 
When the next request is received, you will incease the 3 to 4 and so forth ...

Comment: You do have my point. If you would like to reword the question to make it more clear, please feel free.

Comment: Don't forget file locking.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php -- otherwise, you may have trouble if two users are causing the system to do two writes at once.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger So with this method, would I have to create a queue for the leads that are halted from being processed since the entry log would be locked?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450850/read-and-write-to-a-file-while-keeping-lock. You should lock the the file while you increase the value. Or two simultaneously queries could get the same ID.

Comment: $file_handle = fopen('some/location.txt', 'a+');
 
 while (!flock($file_handle, LOCK_EX )) {
  usleep(round(rand(0, 100)*1000));
 }

 fwrite($file_handle, "data to write");

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to get a unique ID.

If you need a number that corresponds to the number of files, then you could use:

```
$directory = "/csv_folder";
$entryID = count(scandir($directory)) - 2;
```

This counts the number of files in the CSV upload folder. Unless you delete files from there, it would be a unique, sequential number.

Comment: I like the easy to use method, but it doesn't count the total number of entries in the CSV as normal entry ID's would.

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer that gives you the count of already uploaded files.

Comment: You would suggest to use 1 entry per CSV VS. 1 CSV for all entries?

Comment: This solution would count files, and assumes each upload results in a separate CSV file. It all depends what you need to do with the content, and how much concurrency your application must be able to deal with.